# How to I get the copyright meta-data field from an MPMediaItem or AVAsset?

Tags: avfoundation, avasset, mpmedialibrary

Apple's Music App shows meta data like "℗ 2007 Deutsche Grammophon GmbH, Hamburg". I would like to get this field.I do not see a copyright field in `MPMediItem` properties. There is an AV constant `AVMetadataiTunesMetadataKeyCopyright` which I tried to find by making an `AVURLAsset` with the item, but I do not see that key in any of the items `AVAsset.metadata` arrays.

The question is, how do I get that field?

Comment: I tried going low level, using AudioFileGetProperty. On my test device I have about 27 albums. For most of them, the Music App shows a copyright. But I only see a copyright key in one of the albums even with AudioFileGetProperty.

Comment: If I look at the m4a binary, I see the copyright field. It is beginning to look like the call I need is not exposed in the iOS APIs.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to an example audio file? This would be useful to concretely see/verify what you're seeing.

Comment: Not easily: these are all files that have a genuine copyright: i can't copy them to a website, since I would violate the copyright!

Comment: What is the 1) container (file) format?   2) audio codec?

Comment: I am using MP to get the assetURLs of items in a music library. MPMediaItem does not have a copyright property, so I tried creating an AVAsset with the URL. In one case in my tests, I was able to find a copyright. In all other cases, there was no copyright, even thought the Music app using the same albums showed it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to look into [non-iTunes metadata keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationMetadataKeyReference/index.html), as there are many kinds of metadata in media files depending on the container & codec. For example, Apple advertises these [keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationMetadataKeyReference/index.html):

- Common Metadata Keys
- ID3 Metadata Keys
- iTunes Metadata Keys
- QuickTime User Data Keys
- QuickTime Metadata Keys

If your codec is MP3, then the copyright information may live in an [ID3 tag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3) in the header of the MP3 file itself. In this case, it may be useful to use [ID3_Metadata_Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationMetadataKeyReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/ID3_Metadata_Keys):

```
AVMetadataID3MetadataKeyCopyright: String
AVMetadataID3MetadataKeyDate: String
```

**UPDATE:**
Since the files are .m4a, one solution is to use a command-line-tool like [mp4v2](https://code.google.com/p/mp4v2/) to view the [metadata for .m4a apple lossless (ALAC) files](https://nelsonslog.wordpress.com/2012/02/02/metadata-for-m4a-apple-lossless-alac-files/), then you'll know if and where the metadata exists and what keys make sense to use.

Comment: The files are .m4a - all Apple lossless.

Comment: Have you looked at values from other keys? .m4a is MPEG-4, so another idea is to try ffmpeg in the console to print out the metadata (http://jonhall.info/how_to/dump_and_load_metadata_with_ffmpeg). This may give a hint about what keys to use programmatically.